# Data added in Request session lost when using HttpResponseRedirect between views

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions, django-request

I have an API, in which if the user is not permitted to access it, am redirecting it to another view along with a user message adding to request session and using that info am using django message framework to display the message in templates. **In this process the session data passed from one view is lost while I look in the redirected view.** And this is happening only in Production environments.

Here is the code.

Views -

```
def data_asset_alert_track(request, edf_data_asset_id):
    data_asset = EdfDataAsset.objects.get(data_asset_id=edf_data_asset_id)
    x_app_role = access_control.get_xapp_role(request)
    roles = access_control.get_roles(x_app_role)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    is_edit_permitted = (access_control.has_edit_all_access(roles, 'edfdataasset'))\
                        or (True if data_asset.owner_id and data_asset.owner.owner_id == user.username else False)\
                        or (access_control.is_auth_user(data_asset.owner, user) if data_asset.owner_id else False)
    if not is_edit_permitted:
        request.session['message'] = 'Unauthorized Action: Edit DataAsset - %s not permitted'%data_asset.data_asset_name
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('data_assets'))

    if data_asset.alert_fl is False:
       data_asset.alert_fl = 'True'
    else:
       data_asset.alert_fl = 'False'

    data_asset.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))

Redirected to view- 
def data_assets(request):  
    if 'message' in request.session:
        logr.info("There is a message")
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "A trial message")
    data_asset_list = EdfDataAsset.objects.select_related('provider').order_by('data_asset_name')
    field_filter = DataAssetFilter(request.GET, queryset=data_asset_list)
    context = {'data_asset_list': data_asset_list, 'filter': field_filter, }
    return render(request, 'edf/data_assets.html', context)
```

This works completely fine in all dev and test environments. What could be the issue?

I tried adding these two settings in settings.py. Still it does not work

MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

Answer (score 0):

As you return `HttpResponseRedirect`, I do not think your request will go though middleware - meaning your session will not be saved.

To handle this properly, I suggest you use Django's 
. Directly into your `data_asset_alert_track` view.

That should give
in your view

```py
def data_asset_alert_track(request, edf_data_asset_id):
    data_asset = EdfDataAsset.objects.get(data_asset_id=edf_data_asset_id)
    x_app_role = access_control.get_xapp_role(request)
    roles = access_control.get_roles(x_app_role)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    is_edit_permitted = (access_control.has_edit_all_access(roles, 'edfdataasset'))\
                        or (True if data_asset.owner_id and data_asset.owner.owner_id == user.username else False)\
                        or (access_control.is_auth_user(data_asset.owner, user) if data_asset.owner_id else False)
    if not is_edit_permitted:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unauthorized Action: Edit DataAsset - %s not permitted')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('data_assets'))

    if data_asset.alert_fl is False:
       data_asset.alert_fl = 'True'
    else:
       data_asset.alert_fl = 'False'

    data_asset.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

in your redirect view

```py
def data_assets(request):  
    data_asset_list = EdfDataAsset.objects.select_related('provider').order_by('data_asset_name')
    field_filter = DataAssetFilter(request.GET, queryset=data_asset_list)
    context = {'data_asset_list': data_asset_list, 'filter': field_filter, }
    return render(request, 'edf/data_assets.html', context)
```

Comment: Had tried this. This doesn't work too. @Julien Kieffer